# What does $\!\bmod(n,x^r-1)$ mean? [in AKS primality test]

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, prime-numbers, primality-test

Where does a layman go to get a basic understanding of AKS primality testing. I am not talking about the optimal choice of $r$ (which I am told is the hardcore number-theoretic part of the algorithm). I mean basic things, like what does $\bmod(n, x^r-1)$ mean (how can something be mod two things?) And what does binomial expansion have to do with anything?  I can't find anything in Wikipedia that is appropriate for my level.

Comment: Please tell us more about "your level". Do you know about congruence arithmetic and/or the ring of integers modulo m, and, if so, are you familiar with polynomials over such rings?

Answer (score 9):

Informally $\!\bmod(n,\ x^r - 1)\,$ denotes polynomial arithmetic assuming that  $\,n = 0 = x^r -1.\,$ Using these assumptions we can reduce  an integer coefficient polynomial to normal form form as follows. Reduce all coefficients $\!\bmod n,\,$ then substitute $\,x^r = 1,\, $ so $\ x^{r+1} =x,\,\ x^{r+2} = x^2,\ \ldots\,$ hence we can reduce all exponents to be $< r.\,$ Indeed,  we can replace all of the exponents of $\,x\,$ by their remainders  $\!\bmod r,\, $ by [modular order reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/242).

This yields a polynomial of degree $ < r\,$ with coefficients between $\,0\,$ and $\,n-1.\,$ Two polynomials are congruent $\!\bmod (n,\ x^r-1)\,$ iff they have the same reduced normal forms (or, equivalently, if their difference reduces to $0\,$). This reduction is the same as using the the Division Algorithm to reduce a polynomial by mapping it to its  remainder after division by $\, x^r-1\,,\,$ doing coefficient arithmetic $\bmod n,\,$ i.e. by considering the polynomials as being over the coefficient ring $\,\mathbb Z/n =\, $ integers $\!\bmod n$.

Just as we use integer congruences $\!\bmod n\,$ to mimic the quotient ring $ \,\Bbb Z_n = \Bbb Z/n,\,$ the above is using congruences to mimic the quotient ring $\,\Bbb Z[x]/(n,x^r-1)$ where the notation $\,(n,x^r-1)$ denotes the ideal $\,n\:\!\Bbb Z[x]+(x^r-1)\:\!\Bbb Z[x]\subset \Bbb Z[x].\,$ [Similarly, more generally,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/815450/242) a congruence $\!\bmod\!\!(a,b)\,$ on a ring $ \,R\,$ mimics the quotient ring $R/(a,b)$.

Comment: Could you please give a numerical example of reducing a polynomial? Better yet, could you please give a detailed example of an AKS proof? Or point to one somewhere on the internet?

Answer (score 6):

I will address the two question that are directly stated. If you ask more, I can change this answer.

To mod by two things, in this case a number and a polynomial, is not as bad as it might seem. Modding by the number n is just as before - treat every coefficient separately. So $16x^2 + 10x + 7 \equiv x^2 + 2 \mod 5$. The polynomial modulus is a little stranger. But in the case where it's $x^k - 1$, this just means that you reduce all exponents greater than $k$ by $k$, effectively dividing polynomials that are "too large" by a smaller polynomial.

Many more sources exist. [Here](http://www.scottaaronson.com/writings/prime.pdf) is a great primer. [This](http://www.instantlogic.net/publications/PRIMES%20is%20in%20P%20little%20FAQ.htm) is a short FAQ aimed at the AKS. And [here](http://fatphil.org/maths/AKS/) is a list of other sources or learning about the AKS algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure it's suitable for the layman, nor indeed whether there is an account of AKS that is suitable for the layman, but the book [Primality Testing in Polynomial Time](http://www.springer.com/computer/theoretical+computer+science/book/978-3-540-40344-9) by Dietzfelbinger is very nice.