# What courses does one need to follow to understand the AKS primality test?

Tags: prime-numbers, education

I want to study to understand such algorithms as the AKS specifically but as I am new to this I do not know where to start?

Comment: Do you know modular arithmetic? If not, learn it. It's very easy and will help you a lot when learning about more advanced subjects.

Comment: @Mastrem yes I do. But I understand it has to do with group theory and such right?

Comment: The aks test...

Comment: Well, the test itself is an equivalence relation mod $n$, so modular arithmetic would at least be a start. There are some playlists on youtube about group theory, most of it is pretty basic but also not hard to understand.

Comment: @Mastrem and I asume then that that is all you need or are there many more subjects needed to understand aks?

Comment: @Mastrem I am very sorry for being a bit uneducated I meant the whole algorithm and the optimizations that make it fast. Not only the test. I am sorry.

Comment: No problem, I've never really looked into it myself. I'm just looking at the wikipedia page here and looking at what you'll need at least to understand the test. If you don't understand the test, you can't really understand the optimizations of the test. I suggest you take a look at http://www-alg.ist.hokudai.ac.jp/~thomas/SEMINAR/notes.pdf and if you don't understand it, simply google it or look at wikipedia. It seems like you'll need a bit of group theory, modular arithmetic, Fermat's little theorem and the binomial theorem.

Comment: by the way, those notes aren't mine or anything, I just googled 'primes in p' and this was the first thing that came up.

Comment: In the appendix of those notes, they say exactly what you need to know with examples and all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52221/understanding-aks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book [Primality Testing in Polynomial Time](http://www.springer.com/computer/theoretical+computer+science/book/978-3-540-40344-9) by Dietzfelbinger is very nice and tries to give all basic concepts.