# Cancelling terms in polynomial congruence

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, modular-arithmetic

If we have a polynomial like $f(x)=x^{18}+7x^{13}-2x^5+8$. If we want to consider it mod 5 for example, can we simplify it like by subtracting terms (or adding multiples) in 5's; for example, is $f(x)$ equal to $x^{18}+2x^{13}+3x^5+3$ mod 5? I think I've seen this done before but it feels like this shouldn't be possible. And if it is (or isn't), why is that?

Comment: Yes its perfectly OK and a frequent practice to simplify the calculations.

Comment: The equality follows via definition of congruence. The difference of old and new polynomial is divisible by $5$.

Comment: Thank you, the difference analogy really helped.

Comment: You may find helpful [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/52230/242)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is perfectly fine. In you example, because $5\equiv0\pmod{5}$, also $5x^5,5x^{13}\equiv0\pmod{5}$, and hence
\begin{eqnarray*}
f(x)&=&x^{18}+7x^{13}-2x^5+8\\&\equiv&(x^{18}+7x^{13}-2x^5+8)+(-5x^{13}+5x^5-5)\\
&=&x^{18}+2x^{13}+3x^5+3\pmod{5}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Similarly, as suggested in the comments, the difference between the two polynomials equals
$$-5x^{13}+5x^5-5=5(-x^{13}+x^5-1),$$
which is a multiple of $5$. So the two polynomials are congruent modulo $5$.